# nodejs: how to prevent send module cache control overrides htaccess cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

```
<FilesMatch ""> 
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".*"> 
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, s-maxage=604800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js)">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, s-maxage=604800, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have added cache to static assets like css, js, svgs using htaccess. These cache settings are not reflecting in the application since it is overridden by the below code in express send module.

```
  if (this._cacheControl && !res.getHeader('Cache-Control')) {
    var cacheControl = 'public, max-age=' + Math.floor(this._maxage / 1000)
    debug('cache-control %s', cacheControl)
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', cacheControl) // this line is responsible for that
  }
```

When I comment the setHeader code above, htaccess cache settings sets cache correctly to assets. But the passport authentication fails. Like the authentication session is not set when the setHeader line is commented out.
So how to prevent overriding cache set by the htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cache-Control` can be disable by setting the [`cacheControl`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#cachecontrol) option to `false`:

> **cacheControl**
>
> Enable or disable setting `Cache-Control` response header, defaults to `true`.  Disabling this will ignore the `immutable` and `maxAge` options.

```
app.use('/', express.static('./', {
  cacheControl :false
}));
```

The [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html) passes the options through to the [send](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) package that is used to send the file.